# Как сделать owl-nav и owl-dots в одном контейнере?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть карусель картинками, в каждом (owl-item) у меня абсолютом есть текст и навигация тоже
Пробовал оба блока раздельно делать абсолютом, в принципе решил проблему, но если будут добавляться новые картинки для слайдера и их будет больше чем 6шт., тогда досты будут налазить на стрелочки навигации. Хотел бы узнать, может кто сталкивался, как сделать чтобы owl-dots и owl-nav поместить в один контейнер? Чтобы сделать адативно, независимо от кол-ва дотсов. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выровняйте блок с точками по центру, а стрелки раскидайте по бокам. Тогда независимо от количества точек они останутся в центре и не будут наползать на стрелки.

Comment: тоже об этом думал, но по макету у меня должны стрелки от дотсов недалеко находится, а если кину по бокам, боюсь очень ужасно будет, т.к. ширина контейнера карусели 1400px

Comment: ну так недалеко и раскидайте :)) главное что по бокам от точек - на равном удалении от них

Comment: да, это решение проблемы, я так изначально и сделал, но для теста добавил ещё 4-5 айтемов слайдера и они начали налазить. Там может быть и 10 точек, тут уж не знаю даже как поступить

Comment: Если бы Вы привели Ваш код и сделали воспроизводимый пример, Вам бы подсказали оптимальное решение. А так приходится только гадать, увы

Comment: ладно, и на том спасибо:) Поставлю примерно ширину, чтобы влезло 5-6 точек, вряд ли будет больше, и для owl-nav сделаю display:flex, justify-content: space-between и хорошо)